# Is there a way to add (hack) custom SQL to a Core Data fetch?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I know that there isn't a public API for this and you are not really supposed to be doing this.

But say you're using a persistent store of the type `NSSQLiteStoreType`, what are convenient cut points in Core Data to hack custom SQL into a fetch?

I'm thinking of providing a custom subclass of `NSSortDescriptor` and extending the SQL generator. Anyone out there that has looked inside the Core Data framework's private classes, etc. that can give me some hints on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Since the underlying data structure of the SQL table in Core Data is opaque, anything you would be able to do is definitely fragile. The structure can change at anytime without warning, this includes between dot releases of the OS.